# Difference between 妬【ねた】ましい and 羨【うらや】ましい

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

Considering ["How to define 羨ましい?"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4255/542), it does not seem that `羨【うらや】ましい` conveys a strong intensity of jealousy.

How does 妬【ねた】ましい compare to 羨【うらや】ましい then?

Does 妬【ねた】ましい convey a stronger sense of jealously than the "I wish I were you" kind? How is 妬【ねた】ましい used differently from 羨【うらや】ましい?

Also as an aside, has Shakespeare's concept of the green-eyed monster influenced the Japanese language for 緑【みどり】の目【め】 to be considered as a concept for jealousy?

Comment: I'm kind of curious why the kanji for woman is within it.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm. Heaven has no rage like love to hatred turned, nor hell a fury like a woman scorned.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: You can look those kinds of things up in a decent 漢和辞典. For example, in 漢字源 it says 「女+（音符）石（セキ）」で、女性が競争者に負けまいと真っ赤になって興奮すること。(Abbreviated) If you do not have a 漢和辞典, flip through a few at a bookstore and find one that suites your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, `妬ましい` has more of a negative connotation.  Like an "evil" jealousy.  I know in my Japanese Bible, it's often used in talking about "coveting" or "being greedy for".  This dictionary entry includes

> 悪感情がこめられている場合が多い

Whereas `羨ましい` has more of a neutral, or even positive nuance.  "You're going to Disneyland next month?  I'm so jealous!"