# Why is 羨ましい used here instead of a noun like 嫉妬?

Tags: translation

https://www.kosodate.co.jp/bbs/thread.php?id=1027111

> 心の何処かで羨ましいと思ってない？

I'm afraid I don't get the nuance of this sentence.

When an adjective is used with と思う, what does it describe?

What is 羨ましい supposed to mean here?

Comment: Closely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5338/7810

Comment: I like to think 嫉妬 could be combined into the verb [嫉妬む]{«そねた»む}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I completely agree with broccoli forest that you should take a look at the linked thread for the nuance of using 羨ましい vs. 妬ましい (which in this case carries almost the same nuance as 嫉妬), you also asked about using an adjective with 思う, so I'll try to tackle that part of your question as well.

The full sentence you ask about, taken from the thread you linked, is:

> 「みおこさんってグループで仲良くしている人たちのことを、心の何処かで羨ましいと思ってない？」

I'm going to try to break this down into two parts:
1. the usage of 思う with the object marker を
2. the meaning/choice of 羨ましい

1.

With 思う, the object of the thought you are having, i.e. the person/thing you are thinking about, can be referenced using the object marker 「を」.

For some examples I suggest you take a look at [this Weblio page](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/amp/%2522%25E3%2581%25AE%25E3%2581%2593%25E3%2581%25A8%25E3%2582%2592%25E6%2580%259D%25E3%2581%2586%2522).

So if you were to ask:

> 「あの人のことを、(心の何処かで)羨ましいと思っていない？」

you would be asking if the listener considers "that person" to be 羨ましい (somewhere deep down).

You could also in theory ask:

> 「(心の何処かで)あの人に嫉妬してない？」

in which case you would be asking if the listener is jealous of "that person" (somewhere deep down).

2.

This now takes us to your other question, the use of 羨ましい in this context.

Let's first take a look at the definition of 羨ましい.
Pulling from [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%BE%A8%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%84/):

> ［形］［文］うらやま・し［シク］《「うらやむ」の形容詞化》他人の能力や状態をみて、自分もそうありたいと願うさま。また、他人をねたましく思うさま。「兄弟の多い人が―・い」「―・い御身分」

Translating roughly, 羨ましい is the state of looking at someone else's abilities or condition and wishing you could be the same.

In the case of your example, the "someone else" is the グループで仲良くしている人たち.

On the other hand, if the speaker had used 嫉妬する, which has a more negative connotation, they would be assuming that みおこさん wishes ill will on the other party.

I think 回答者 No. 5 on [here](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/4618856.html) did a really good job explaining the difference.

みおこさん doesn't want to wish the other parents any ill will on account of her jealousy (嫉妬), but she DOES wish she could become like them (羨ましい), talking amongst each other when they go to pick up their kids. She even sort of mentions this in her original post!

So in conclusion, the person asking the question is asking if みおこさん could perhaps (somewhere deep down) be looking at the グループで仲良くしている人たち and wishing she could be like them (getting along together / enjoying talking to each other in the group).